# Rails (One Month Rails) NoMethodError in PinsController#create - can't add new pin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, nomethoderror

When I try to add a new pin, I can't. Instead, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in PinsController#create

undefined method `name' for #<pin:0x000001011b9638>
```

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

```
app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:48:in `block in create'
app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:47:in `create'
```

Request

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"n9E2nob/KBzu20PEzYoQWXnibAUR5TH6iPWNd66383k=",
"pin"=>{"description"=>"stea"},
"commit"=>"Create Pin"}
```

pins_controller.rb

```
def create

@pin = current_user.pins.new(params[:pin])

respond_to do |format|
  if @pin.save
    format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @pin, status: :created, location: @pin }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

app/model/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name

has_many :pins, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

routes.rb

```
Omrails::Application.routes.draw do
 resources :pins

 devise_for :users

 root :to => 'pages#home'
 get 'about' => 'pages#about'
```

app/models/pin.rb

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description

  validates :description, presence: true
    validates :name, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
    validates :user_id, presence: true
 end
```

db/migrate/create_pins

```
class CreatePins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pins do |t|
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

db/migrate/add_user_id_to_pins.rb

```
class AddUserIdToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pins, :user_id, :integer
    add_index :pins, :user_id
  end
end
```

db/migrate/add_name_to_users.rb

```
class AddNameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :name, :string
  end
end
```

Any ideas about what has gone wrong?

Not sure if it's relevant, but this used to work. I was able to follow along [Mattan Griffel's One Month Rails course -- Add Assoc bt Pins and Users video](https://onemonthrails.com) until 29m50s but then I realized that I had to skip back to Customizing Devise bec I forgot to add simple forms.

Now that simple forms have been added, I am trying to go forward - and getting stuck here :(

UPDATE: I ran migrate redo for creating pins and adding user id to pins. Then I removed the validate name line. Now I get the following error when I create pin

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in PinsController#new

unknown attribute: user_id 
app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:29:in `new'
```

pins_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pin }
    end
  end
```

Many thanks for helping

db/schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130828163738) do

  create_table "pins", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name =>     "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

end
```

Comment: Have you generated and run the migrations -- `bundle exec rake db:migrate` to add `name` to the `Pin` model?

Comment: thanks @Nerve - I just added the migrations that I did before. Do they look ok? Should I re-run them?

Answer (score 3):

You are validating the presence of `:name` in the `Pin` model but it does not have a `:name` field. Your `User` has.

Just remove the `validates :name, presence: true` from you `Pin` model (line 5).

What happened is that Rails, when trying to save your `Pin` model, will run all the validations. When it encounters the presence validation on `:name`, it will check to see if `@pin.name` isn't blank. But the thing is that your `Pin` model does not have a name method. So it raises this error.

If you actually want your `Pin` model to have a `name`, add it the to `pins` table:

```
$ rails g migration add_name_to_pins name:string
$ rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Thanks @delba. I'm not sure how to fix that. Can you help me out with specific pointers? I just tried to redo the migrations but that seems to have made things messier.

Comment: @SharlaS I just updated my answer. Run `rake db:setup` if you get lost with your migrations. It will recreate your tables and run the migrations. Do not use it if you have critical data stored in the db.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, @delba. I followed your suggestion, but now I have a new 'unknown attribute error.' I will add details above - hopefully easily resolved.

Comment: @SharlaS `unknown attribute :user_id` => you accidentally removed the `user_id` field from your pins_table. Did you run `rake db:setup`? Show me your `schema` (db/schema.rb)

Comment: I don't think I ran rake db:setup but maybe it was done while installing rails and customizing with Bootstrap and Devise, if that makes sense? I posted the db/schema.rb. thank you for helping me!

Comment: `rails g migration add_user_id_to_pins user:references` `rake db:migrate`

Comment: I have not solved the problem yet but I will update once I do! thanks @delba